# Flagging entities on behalf of nodes.. Is a dummy user account attached to the node the only way?

Tags: 7, entities, flags

Scenario:
A central node with a field collection that references (entity references) other nodes of Type A.
When viewing Type A nodes, a view shows the field collection items with a non-global flag link.
The flag would be for the Type A node, not any site users.

I don't need any help creating the view etc.

Possible Solution:
When node of Type A is created, a dummy user account is created using rules and is referenced by the node.
The view showing field collection items and the flag link are set up to act as that dummy user.

I don't actually need any help with doing this but I feel like there has to be a better way. This will result in thousands of dummy user accounts for what is a fairly small site feature.

Any non-coding alternatives welcome.. I'm in a bit of a rush with this feature.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're using the flag for.

Comment: Lots of classes making progress through a course. The course node has a field collection with all of the parts of the course and I want to let class nodes flag them as they progress.

Comment: shouldn't be the student (user) be the one making progress through a course?

Comment: This is for teachers tracking what they've done. Students flag study / exam nodes that reference the course but I want teachers to flag field collection items for what they've taught. It's an important feature in this niche where teachers are carefully monitored and there are lots of subs and cancellations. It probably wouldn't be applicable to normal schools / universities.